# My settings reset to default upon reboot

Tags: reboot, settings, default

So I bought a used Dell Latitude 2110 laptop for 20 dollars on eBay and it had Ubuntu Linux installed from Windows 7. I only use it for web browsing and word processing. I like the program so far, but I am having an issue when I reboot my computer where all personal settings are reset to  the default. I am also having an issue where I cannot add a password or user profile to the computer because it again resets whenever I reboot the computer. Is there something that I can change in settings to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does the computer only have Ubuntu or does it also have Windows?

Comment: It only has Ubuntu. I just found out that it wipes all documents and files upon reboot, too.

Comment: Sounds like since you don't have anything else on the computer to lose, it might be best to just do a clean install of Ubuntu.

Comment: So I just need to reinstall the operating system? Ideally I would be able to restore my files

Comment: Yes, that is what I would try. If that doesn't solve the issue, there's likely a deeper problem that might be related to your computer's hardware.

Comment: Okay, so I need to create a bootable USB drive with ubuntu on it and boot with the USB drive and overwrite the existing software? I'm new to all this.

Comment: Yes, that's right. There are plenty of tutorials out there that are helpful with this. This one here looks pretty good: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick